# Unexpected token e thrown by JSON.parse

Tags: jquery, json, filereader

I am trying to read a JSON object from a file using FileReader.
This json file contains the following:

```
{"markers": [
        {
            "point":new GLatLng(40.266044,-74.718479), 
            "homeTeam":"Lawrence Library",
            "awayTeam":"LUGip",
            "markerImage":"images/red.png",
            "information": "Linux users group meets second Wednesday of each month.",
            "fixture":"Wednesday 7pm",
            "capacity":"",
            "previousScore":""
        },
        {
            "point":new GLatLng(40.211600,-74.695702),
            "homeTeam":"Hamilton Library",
            "awayTeam":"LUGip HW SIG",
            "markerImage":"images/white.png",
            "information": "Linux users can meet the first Tuesday of the month to work out harward and configuration issues.",
            "fixture":"Tuesday 7pm",
            "capacity":"",
            "tv":""
        },
        {
            "point":new GLatLng(40.294535,-74.682012),
            "homeTeam":"Applebees",
            "awayTeam":"After LUPip Mtg Spot",
            "markerImage":"images/newcastle.png",
            "information": "Some of us go there after the main LUGip meeting, drink brews, and talk.",
            "fixture":"Wednesday whenever",
            "capacity":"2 to 4 pints",
            "tv":""
        },
] }
```

This is the code I have written:

```
var jsonClean = function(jsonText)  {
            return jsonText.replace(/\n/g, "").replace(/\r/g, "").replace(/\t/g, "");
        };

        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
            console.log('Uploading...');
            var uploader = ($('input#fileUpload'))[0];
            var fileList = uploader.files;
            console.log(fileList.length);
            if(fileList.length > 0){
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.addEventListener('load',function(loadEvent){
                    if(reader.readyState == FileReader.DONE){
                        var jsonObject = jsonClean(reader.result);
                        console.log(jsonObject);
                        $('#jsonView').empty();
                        $('#jsonView').JSONView(JSON.parse(jsonObject));
                      }
               });
                    reader.readAsText(fileList[0]);

                }
            } 
    else {
          alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
        }
```

jsonObject as printed by console.log():

> {"markers": [{"point":new GLatLng(40.266044,-74.718479), "homeTeam":"Lawrence Library","awayTeam":"LUGip","markerImage":"images/red.png","information": "Linux users group meets second Wednesday of each month.","fixture":"Wednesday 7pm","capacity":"","previousScore":""},{"point":new GLatLng(40.211600,-74.695702),"homeTeam":"Hamilton Library","awayTeam":"LUGip HW SIG","markerImage":"images/white.png","information": "Linux users can meet the first Tuesday of the month to work out harward and configuration issues.","fixture":"Tuesday 7pm","capacity":"","tv":""},{"point":new GLatLng(40.294535,-74.682012),"homeTeam":"Applebees","awayTeam":"After LUPip Mtg Spot","markerImage":"images/newcastle.png","information": "Some of us go there after the main LUGip meeting, drink brews, and talk.","fixture":"Wednesday whenever","capacity":"2 to 4 pints","tv":""},] }

'Uncaught SyntaxError:Unexpected token e' is thrown when JSONView() is called.

Can someone please point out what is wrong with the code?Thanks.

Comment: You're mixing an object (that's where "json" comes from - it means "JavaScript Object Notation" because objects are native to javascript) and a string (you can't use `.replace` on an object). Anything that has `new` in it without quotes is not valid JSON, but it _is_ a valid javascript object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not valid JSON, for starters. These bits: `new GLatLng(40.266044,-74.718479)`

...cannot be JavaScript class constructors; change them to be one of the types defined in [the JSON spec](http://json.org).

Comment: ..or booleans, NULL, ints or floats as well as sub-objects.

Comment: Oh..I was just trying this as an example..I googled for json files and this is what came up. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @h2ooooooo haha yeah I was being incredibly lazy. Fixed.